# Iterating a range of integers in Go templates

Tags: templates, loops, go

I'm trying to do an iteration in the template for pagination but there doesn't seem to be a way to do a for iteration.

Instead of

```
{{range $i, $e := .aSlice}}
```

I want to do something like this

```
{{range $i := 1 .. 10}}
    <div>{{$i}}</div>
{{end}}
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the least amount of work you can use the package [github.com/bradfitz/iter](http://godoc.org/github.com/bradfitz/iter) for that.
It provides a function `N` which you can use like this:

```
{{range $i, $_ := N 10}}
    <div>{{$i}}</div>
{{end}}
```

Use the `Funcs` method on the template to add the function `N` like this:

```
myTemplate.Funcs(template.FuncMap{"N": iter.N})
```

For `1..m` instead of `0..m` use `N m+1` and ignore the `0`:

```
{{range $i, $_ := N 11}}
    {{if $i}}
        <div>{{$i}}</div>
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

Of course you can solve this completely different. Just define your own function that takes
two parameters and creates a stream of integers for example ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/MVWAF0md0c)):

```
func N(start, end int) (stream chan int) {
    stream = make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := start; i <= end; i++ {
            stream <- i
        }
        close(stream)
    }()
    return
}

templ := `{{range $i := N 1 10}}
            <div>{{$i}}</div>
      {{end}}`

t := template.New("foo").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"N": N})
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with the second option. It's weird though that this is not provided in the standard library.

Comment: If you really think this should be included you can always open a ticket [here](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list). However, go makes it really easy to use third party libraries, so the only major drawback I see is that I can't use these in examples on play.golang.org :)